# Redux not re-rendering if I add a `connect()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using React Router with Redux. Here's my router:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <RouteFrame>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomeRoute}/>
            <Route path="/map" component={MapRoute}/
          </Switch>
        </RouteFrame>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
```

And in my RouteFrame.js

```
class RouteFrame extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="routeFrame"
        className={this.props.isSidebarShown ? 'sidebarShown' : 'sidebarHidden'}
      >
        <Header/>
        <div id="body">
          <Sidebar/>
          <div id="main">
            {this.props.children}
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  isSidebarShown: state.ui.isSidebarShown,
}))(RouteFrame);
```

When I update the route by calling `dispatch(push(path));`, the address bar changes, but the UI doesn't. The `render` method of RouteFrame isn't being ran. If I change the value of `state.ui.isSidebarShown`, the `render` method of RouteFrame runs and the correct route is displayed. This makes me think that `connect()` is preventing RouteFrame from re-rendering, even though `props.children` has changed.

If I remove the `connect()` (i.e. I just do `export default RouteFrame;`), the routing works properly.

How do I make Redux update RouteFrame after the route changes?

Comment: Are you using `react-router-redux` ? The router should change the state, so the components will re-render after a route change.

Comment: Yes I'm using `react-router-redux`. It's not re-rendering if I have the `connect()`.